# Can my warlord use different skills during the same battle?

Tags: blood-brothers

I have just got the latest update and we can now add up to 3 skills to our warlord, but how do these skills work in a battle?

Will the skill be chosen at random at the start? or is it possible to use multiple in the same battle? is it possible for my warlord to use 3 different skills in the same battle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question directly, it is definitely possible to use more than one skill in the same battle.

I recently did this by performing "Rush" and "Triple Strike" in the same battle.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read on other posts, you can only proc one skill from each category (opener,attack, defense) on every attack. So if all your skill are from different categories then all 3 could proc on one attack. If you have two from same category then only one will proc, per attack. But if you are talking about throughout a whole battle, then yeah you will probably be able to use all of your skills (even if they are all attack ex.) if you stay alive long enough and are able to get in enough attacks. Which skill will proc is selected randomly before each attack.

I'm not sure, but I don't believe that adding two skills from the same cat will lower proc rate. I don't know why it would. But, it probably would not help either because you are still only getting one skill that procs (per category).

Comment: Thats what I read too, but this forum post is trying to prove the contrary. http://www.bloodbrothersrpg.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=22425

Comment: This is wrong, you can definitely do two different moves in the same battle. I recently did "Rush" and "Triple Strike" in the same battle.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use 1 skill per skill type in a battle. IE you *can* equip two different ATK skills, but it's not beneficial since only one will be used per battle. Which one gets used is also random.

Having more than one skill per type is bad because it will lower the overall proc rate. It would be best to either have 1 skill per type (Opener, Attack, Defensive) or stack multiple skills. This way all skills can be used and none will be wasted.

Comment: Hmmm.. not sure about this. Last night I had a PvP battle against The Purple Knife (think that's the right one), and she used her default move (thundercloud maybe?) and she also used "Berserk" in the same battle. I assume these are both "Attack" type skills, so if they are this means you answer is not correct.

Comment: I'm thinking it also has to do with the primary attribute of the skill as well. Thundercloud is WIS, while Berserk is ATK

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is based more on a roll style  proc, say you have 3 of the same skill.. torrent of flame, well it is maxed out so 30%. Your main will roll once for a 3/10 chance of using the skill, then if it misses roll a 3/10 chance for the second and third to succeed. Not entirely positive its true but I did stack torrent of flame twice on my WK to see and with 30% on triple strike and two torrents on 11% torrent comes up more often than the triple, so it has to stack in some sort of way..

Comment: This does sound like it could be the case, but do you have anything to backup your suggestions? If so, I could accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

That is not necessarily a 'stack'. While it does mean that torrent will come up at more often than triple strike, it's merely because of the 2/3 to 1/3 ratio by having two of them. Meaning that if you have two torrents at 30% and one triple at 30%, while torrent will trigger 75% more the time than triple, there is still only a 30% of ANY skill triggering on any given attack.

Comment: To put it simply.. having 3 torrent skills at 30% would be no different than having 1 torrent skill at 30% so no need to waste the money and time. :)